# emacs doremi: to change color-themes

Tags: emacs, color-scheme

I'm trying to get doremi working in emacs. Specifically, at this stage, to allow me to quickly scroll through a condensed list of color-themes and see each theme as I go through it. For this I would use the 'M-x doremi-color-themes+' command.

**What I've done**:

Installed color-themes (successfull)

Installed doremi.el, doremi-cmd.el, ring+.el and added

```
(add-to-list 'loadpath "~/elisp/themes")
(add-to-list 'loadpath "~/elisp/doremi/")
(require 'color-theme)                                                                                                                                                              
(color-theme-initialize)                                                                                                                                                            
(color-theme-classic)                                                                                                                                                               

 ;; create a list of color themes to scroll through using 'doremi-cmd                                                                                                                
(setq my-color-themes (list 'color-theme-classic                                                                                                                                    
                            'color-theme-retro-green                                                                                                                                
                            'color-theme-gray30                                                                                                                                     
                            'color-theme-subtle-hacker                                                                                                                              
                            'color-theme-jonadabian-slate))                                                                                                                         

(require 'doremi)                                                                                                                                                                   
(require 'doremi-cmd)                                                                                                                                                               
(require 'ring+)
```

to the .emacs file.

**What emacs does**:

When I type the comand 'M-x doremi-color-themes+' into the mini-buffer it seems to accept that I've given it a valid command and tells me to use the  and  arrow keys to move through the list. But when I do that all that happens is the cursor moves up and down in the active window. No changing of color-themes.

Being somewhat new to emacs (and especially customising it) I'm sure I have missed a step or put something in the wrong place. Perhaps there's some sort of (setq 'bla-bla-bla (...)) I need to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bit for back and forth with @Drew we found a solution to the problem.

It turned out the major problem was that I was using emacs in 'terminal mode' rather than as a GUI application. Bare in mind I'm using a mac.

In the context of Terminal, my arrow keys send escape sequences and so doremi cannot read the event as intended. So it just escapes and applies the message to the active buffer.

There is an answer.

By adding the following lines to my .emacs file (or whatever your init file for emacs is) I was able to redirect doremi to use two other keys. ie. not the up and down arrows.

```
(setq doremi-down-keys '(?n))
(setq doremi-up-keys   '(?p))
```

Doing this tells doremi to use 'n' as the down key and 'p' as the up key. And all works just fine.

Because I am only new to the world of programming and computing I may often use incorrect terminology. If this is the case please let me know and I will edit accordingly for clarity and consistency.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for your trouble. Please state your Emacs version (`M-x emacs-version`), and your version of `color-theme.el`.

You do not need to require library [`ring+.el`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs-en/download/ring%2b.el) if you use Emacs 23 or later (its code was included in GnuEmacs 23.)

You do not need to use `(color-theme-initialize)` or `(color-theme-classic)`. The former is done automatically by `doremi-color-themes+`.

Try starting from `emacs -Q` (i.e., no init file, `~/.emacs`), to be sure there is no interference from stuff in your init file.

Your variable `my-color-themes` is not referenced anywhere. Instead of defining that variable, just customize user option `doremi-color-themes`.  (Or leave its value `nil`, which means that all color themes will be cycled through.)

Feel free to contact me by email if you continue to have a problem.  Or continue here, if you prefer.

[Just to be sure: you are using `color-theme.el`, right? There is a lot of confusion out there between Emacs "custom themes" and color themes. [**Do Re Mi**](http://www.emacswiki.org/DoReMi) supports both, but they are different critters.]

Comment: GNU Emacs 24.3.1 (x86_64-apple-darwin13.0.0) of 2013-12-23 on tennine-slave.macports.org and color-theme-6.6.0. Love to email you but I don't know address. Emacs version was updated because you asked and now I can't even get a color theme to load at startup. Can still select from list once started. Doremi no longer recognised. Yay! Seems to be recognising .emacs file because color-theme commands not recognised when starting with $ emacs -Q

Comment: Wait. For some reason I'm able to use command doremi-color-themes+ again, but same problem as before, using the arrow keys does nothing but move cursor in active buffer. Have removed the lines (color-theme-initialize) and (color-theme-classic) from .emacs file.

Comment: Please be sure (for now) that you are starting from `emacs -Q`, and update your post to show a complete recipe to repro the problem: each thing that you do (each keystroke, if not obvious). Put both the color-theme code and the DoReMi code in your `load-path`: `(add-to-list 'load-path "PATH-TO-THE-LISP-FILES")`. Contact info is in the Lisp file header. (Always read a library file header before trying to use the library, just in case it has something helpful to tell you.)